# ¿Como puedo pasar una variable desde un Activity a otra mediante un Intent dentro de un Adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, android-intent, android-adapter

Tengo un adapter para mi RecyclerView donde le programe que al clickear sobre el item (de mi RecyclerView) ejecute un Intent con un putExtra para llevarme a otra activity, la variable que contiene mi putExtra proviene del item que clickeé, pero ahora yo necesito agregar una variable mas que proviene de la activity. La cuestion es que no se como enviarla desde el adapter.

Este es mi Adapter con el Intent

```
package com.example.atipicoapp

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.list_item.view.*

class MyAdapter(private val platoList : ArrayList<Plato>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {






    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {

        val itemView =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)

        itemView.platoTouch.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { v: View ->


        })

        return MyViewHolder(itemView)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val plato: Plato = platoList[position]
        holder.platoName.text = plato.platoName
        holder.platoDescription.text = plato.platoDescription
        holder.platoPrecio.text = plato.platoPrecio.toString()
        holder.platoCantidad.text = plato.platoCantidad.toString()

        when(holder){

            is MyViewHolder -> {

                holder.bind(platoList[position])

            }

        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return platoList.size

    }

    public class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {


        val platoName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoNombre)
        val platoDescription: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoDescripcion)
        val platoPrecio: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoPrecio)

        val platoTouch: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoTouch)

        val platoCantidad: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.platoCant)



        private val mActivity = itemView.context as Activity
        private val intent = Intent(mActivity,SlotActivity::class.java)


        fun bind(plato: Plato){

            platoTouch.setOnClickListener{


                intent.putExtra("id", platoName.text.toString())
                mActivity.startActivity(intent)
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Y este es mi Activity que contiene mi RecyclerView y la variable que quiero enviar.

```
package com.example.atipicoapp

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.firebase.firestore.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_menu_atipico.*

class MenuAtipicoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var platoArrayList: ArrayList<Plato>
    private lateinit var myAdapter: MyAdapter
    private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_atipico)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        platoArrayList = arrayListOf()

        myAdapter = MyAdapter(platoArrayList)

        recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter

        pedidoId = intent.extras?.getString("pedidoId") //Esta es la variable que necesito enviar

        EventChangeListener()

        Setup()

    }

    private fun EventChangeListener() {


        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db.collection("Platos").addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {
            override fun onEvent(
                value: QuerySnapshot?,
                error: FirebaseFirestoreException?
            ) {

                if (error != null) {

                    Log.e("Firestore Error", error.message.toString())
                    return

                }

                for (dc: DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!) {

                    if (dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                        platoArrayList.add(dc.document.toObject(Plato::class.java))

                    }

                }

                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

            }


        })


    }

    private fun Setup() {

        botonAceptar.setOnClickListener {

            val SlotIntent = Intent(this, SlotActivity::class.java).apply {


            }
            startActivity(SlotIntent)
        }

    }

}
```

Gracias de antemano, esta comunidad me ayudo a seguir con mi app

Answer (score 0):

antes de nada la manera en la que estás extrayendo el dato del adapter no es el adecuado, ese tipo de lógica no se debe ejecutar así,  la manera correcta es utilizando una función lambda, simplemente le pasas como parámetro en el constructor del adapter una lambda, similar a la siguiente:
Private val getItemClicked(id:String)->Unit

Luego, le agregas en los parámetros requeridos del viewHolder esa misma lambda y dentro del setOnClickListener del itemView pones así:
getItemClicked(platoName.text.toString())

Luego en la Activity donde tenes la declaración del recyclerView agregas una funcion así:

Fun getName(id:String){
//acá se pone el intent y le pasas
Como putExtra el id
}
Obviamente al haber agregado la lambda como parámetro en el constructor del adapter, te vas a dar cuenta porque te va a pedir que le pases esa función, entonces le pasas esta que acabas de crear de la siguiente manera:

getName(id:String){it}

Perdón por la falta de detalle pero lo estoy escribiendo desde el móvil y sin el Android Studio cerca.